# Implementing logic for XML comparison using python

Tags: python, xml

I have two files in XML which I am able to compare successfully. I have a little doubt in logic that i implemented that takes care of order. Below are two XML files:

A file:

```
<m1:time timeinterval="5">

   <m1:vehicle distance="40" speed="5"\>
   <m1:location hours = "1" path = '1'\>
      <m1:feature color="2" type="a">564</m1:feature>
      <m1:feature color="3" type="b">570</m1:feature>
      <m1:feature color="4" type="c">570</m1:feature>
   <\m1:location>

   <m1:location hours = "5" path = '1'\>
      <m1:feature color="6" type="a">560</m1:feature>
      <m1:feature color="7" type="b">570</m1:feature>
      <m1:feature color="8" type="c">580</m1:feature>   
   <\m1:location>
</m1:time>
```

B file

```
<m1:time timeinterval="6">

   <m1:vehicle distance="40" speed="5"\>
   <m1:location hours = "5" path = '1'\>
      <m1:feature color="6" type="a">560</m1:feature>
      <m1:feature color="7" type="b">570</m1:feature>
      <m1:feature color="8" type="c">580</m1:feature>   
   <\m1:location>

   <m1:location hours = "1" path = '1'\>
      <m1:feature color="2" type="a">564</m1:feature>
      <m1:feature color="3" type="b">570</m1:feature>
      <m1:feature color="4" type="c">570</m1:feature>
   <\m1:location>
</m1:time>
```

**What I tried:**

When I previously asked this question on SO I did not had any kind of implementation in mind about the logic, but now I implemented one logic wherein I have stored the values of 'hours' and 'path' in lists of lists for both files like in following format:

```
         [hours,path]
A_list = [[1,1],[5,1]]

B_list = [[5,1],[1,1]]
```

Now i am willing to compare each list of A_list with every list of B_list for checking equality of color, type attributes.

**What I want:**

If the contents of B_list matches A_list then all the equivalent sub-elements of [1,1] in both files will be compared and printed for difference and that goes same for [5,1]. Also, the output will follow the order of A File. Since the size of both files are above 4 to 5 MB's and such lists are present in plenty simply using 'set' method is not working.

Additionally, I am also totally stuck in thinking about how this approach where after comparing two lists containing just numbers will get me resulting feature attributes of correct location element which are located in huge xml files. All ideas and suggestions are welcomed

Thank you for going through guys.

Comment: All this sounds a tad underspecified. What are "huge" XML files? So huge, that for any practicality you have to resort to a streaming compare? In my experience you should use XML as pure container for structured objects. Comparing data requires strict typing and structure, both of which is no design principle in XML.

Comment: @Vroomfondel by "Huge" i mean it has lots of data inside which is rather disorderly placed in above manner, like some elements not in fix order in both files. Can you elaborate a little about using XML as a pure container for structured objects? do you mean that i should make python structure that saves individual xml data?